# Does $\int_\limits{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(2x)}{x}dx $ absolutely converge?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

My teacher gave me this task to prove it, but I have no idea how to begin.

Can I have any clue?

Comment: If you know about $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx$, then you can either reduce your problem to that, or mimic the proof.

Comment: Make a connection with the harmonic series.

Comment: It doesn't. $\ \ \ $

Answer (score 3):

Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{N\pi/2}\left|\frac{\sin(2x)}{x}\right|\,dx&=\sum_{n=1}^N \int_{(n-1)\pi}^{n\pi}\frac{|\sin(x)|}{x}\,dx\\\\
&\ge \frac1\pi \sum_{n=1}^N\frac1n \int_{(n-1)\pi}^{n\pi}|\sin(x)|\,dx\\\\
&=\frac2\pi \sum_{n=1}^N \frac1n
\end{align}$$

Inasmuch as the harmonic series diverges, the integral fails to be absolutely convergent.

Comment: For some reason someone convinced me that I can prove it to be absolutely converging. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  -Mark

Answer (score 1):

Look for intervals where $\sin(2x)$ is bounded away from zero.

Comment: I know how to prove that $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{sin(2x)}{x} dx $  converges but how can we prove that $\int_{0}^{\infty}| \frac{sin(2x)}{x} |dx$ converges too?

Comment: @EitanKosman: though not explicitly, Martin answered your question. Dr MV was more explicit.